# Looking for a SVG library for construction

Tags: qgis, svg

Would anyone be able to suggest a good library for svg symbols for construction please? To be used in QGIS. Ideally water and pipeline network symbols.

ciao

Answer (score 3):

you can check out map icons collection [here](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/). they are not format of svg, but you can convert them for your needs.

[image: icons]

i hope it helps you...